# Rule for derivative of an unknown function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, replacement

I am taking the derivative of a function with respect to another function, e.g.

`D[g[f[x,y]],f[x,y]]`

This outputs `g'(f(x,y))`, as expected. How can I specify a rule for this derivative?

I've tried the following:

`Derivative[g[f[x_,y_]][f[x_, k_]]] := f[y, k]`

but apparently this isn't the output of `D[]`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try: `Derivative[g[f[x_, y_]][f[x_, k_]]] := g'[f[y, k]]`

Comment: This doesn't appear to do anything....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you have a random expression

```
expr = D[g[f[x, y]], f[x, y]] + 2 x + 2 f[x, y] + g[f[x, y]] + 
   Log[D[g[f[x, y]], f[x, y]]];
```

that looks like this

```
expr
```

> [image: exp]

you can write a replacement rule like so:

```
rule = Derivative[1][g][f[x, y]] -> 
    HHH[x, y];
```

and then

```
expr /. rule
```

gives

> [image: res]

To understand the above, I suggest that you take a look at the [**`FullForm`**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullForm.html?v=13.2) of the expression for which you wanted to set a rule originally, i.e `D[g[f[x, y]], f[x, y]] // FullForm`